# What practical powers do angels have?

Tags: theology, malach-angel

In Jewish theology, what practical physical powers do angels have? How far can they intervene in our world while on a mission? Are those powers linked to the "name" they have for their mission or come with their relative degree (מעלה, as in [Rambam's Yesodey Hatorah](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Mishneh_Torah%2C_Foundations_of_the_Torah.2.7?vhe=Torat_Emet_363&lang=bi)).

For example, in [Job.1.16](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Job.1.16?lang=en&with=Rashi&lang2=en) Satan incites people on raids, blows the wind, brings down fire, and kills innocent gentiles.

Comment: There are lots of sources that point to specific malachim who have a shlita over certain elements e.g Gavriel being the malach of fire...

Comment: @Dov Isn't a fiery sword specifically used by Gavriel to stop the evil sorcerer Balaam on his donkey?

Comment: According to the simple reading of the verse it just says the angel was holding a sword (not necessarily a flaming one)?

Comment: @llja - it says in Bamidbar Rabbah 12:8 https://www.sefaria.org/Bamidbar_Rabbah.12.8?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en that Gavriel was made of/in charge of fire.

Comment: This is why he was tasked with destroying Sodom which included the raining down of sulphurous fire (see Rashbam Bereishis 18:14 - https://www.sefaria.org/Rashbam_on_Genesis.18.14.1?ven=Sefaria_Community_Translation&lang=en&with=all&lang2=en). He was also present with Chananya, Mishael and Azariah in the fiery furnace (see Rabbeinu Bachya Vayikra 10:2 - https://www.sefaria.org/Rabbeinu_Bahya%2C_Vayikra.10.2.2?ven=Torah_Commentary_by_Rabbi_Bachya_ben_Asher,_trans._Eliyahu_Munk,_1998.&lang=en )

Comment: @Dov MB, might've mixed up something. Had that image of the Archangel Gavriel with a fiery sword in hand in head. Though that might not be too far stretched

Comment: @Ilja - A reference to fiery swords is in Bereishis 3:24 about the Keruvim who guard the entrances of Gan Eden - https://www.sefaria.org/Genesis.3.24?ven=Tanakh:_The_Holy_Scriptures,_published_by_JPS&lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en